# Resetting an array to an empty array does not work

Tags: jquery, arrays, key, keyevent

What am I doing wrong? It seems that the array is not cleared after the function was called.

If you press first <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl+alt+c</kbd> the second function will not called (only if you press it a second time).

```
var key = function (keys, fn) {
  var arr = [];
  $(document).on({
    keydown: function (e) {
      arr.push(e.which);
      if (arr.join(', ') === keys) {
        fn(e);
        arr = [];
      }
    },
    keyup: function (e) {
      arr = [];
    }
  });
};

// ctrl + c
key('17, 67', function (e) {
  alert('ctrl+c');
});

// ctrl + alt + c
key('17, 18, 67', function () {
  alert('ctrl+alt+c');
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/WucCQ/0)**.

Comment: NB: this is not a good way of trapping key sequences.  1. it registers an additional `keydown` and `keyup` handler for _every_ sequence - that doesn't scale 2. ctrl-alt-N is normally treated the same as alt-ctrl-N

Comment: Plus there's the problem when you hold down a key and it ends up in the array multiple times, as well as not registering holding down `ctrl` and pressing 'c' multiple times, not just once and then lifting all fingers.

Comment: @Archer you're completely correct! Any ideas to get around this problem and still be simple?

Comment: @Alnitak Your first point is clear. But can you explain the 2nd one a bit? For example if i press `c+ctrl` it does not copy anything ;)

Comment: @yckart it's different for single meta key sequences - I was talking about sequences with multiple meta keys.  You always press the non-meta key last, but it shouldn't matter which order you press the meta keys.

Comment: @Alnitak ah ok, thanks i understand now what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code isn't the array.

Your keyup is not being called because you release the key when you see the alert window

Check the same code working in here: http://jsfiddle.net/WucCQ/1/   - Watch the console log

```
var key = function (keys, fn) {
  var arr = [];
  $(document).on({
    keydown: function (e) {
      arr.push(e.which);
      if (arr.join(', ') === keys) {
        fn(e);
        arr = [];
      }
    },
    keyup: function (e) {
      arr = [];
    }
  });
};

// ctrl + c
key('17, 67', function (e) {
  console.log('ctrl+c');
});

// ctrl + alt + c
key('17, 18, 67', function () {
  console.log('ctrl+alt+c');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This code is not good as appeared. It will not see the difference between <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Cltrl+C+V</kbd>!

Try this code:

```
var key = function (keys, fn) {  
  $(document).on({
    keydown: function (e) {
      var arr = [];
      if(e.ctrlKey)
        arr.push("17");
      if(e.altKey)
        arr.push("18");
      arr.push(e.which);
      if (arr.join(', ') === keys) {
        fn(e);        
      }
    }
  });
};

// ctrl + c
key('17, 67', function (e) {
  alert('ctrl+c');
});

// ctrl + alt + d
key('17, 18, 68', function () {
  alert('ctrl+alt+c');
});
```

Instead of collecting pressed keys into global array, you can check if it is pressed when keydown event happens. This works fine for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/27WGw/2/ 
(**Note** that I changed Ctrl+Alt+c to Ctrl+Alt+d as the first one is a global hotkey on my machine)

Comment: Not really practical, a little too undynamic

Comment: What do you mean under undynamic?

Comment: @yckart - I think you've misunderstood something.  This works perfectly.

Comment: @Archer Not really... press something like `ctrl+v+c` results in `true`.

Comment: @yckart He's answered the question, as asked, perfectly.  If there's an issue with the answer then you need to clarify the question :)

Comment: @yckart You are right. Ctrl+v+c will return true with my code, when it should not do that.